# Grid lines not showing in D3 histogram

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm playing around with different kinds of D3 charts and for this particular example, I can't seem to get the grid lines to show up. I've compared it to a similar example I have where the lines show up but I still can't make sense of it. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o4644zrj/1/) of what I have at the moment.

I'm mainly interested in the horizontal grid lines so here is the code for when I add the y-axis:

```
var gy = svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'y axis')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
    .call(yAxis);

gy.selectAll('g').filter(function(d) {
  return d;
})
.classed('minor', true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the tick size to set the size of the horizontal grid lines. Width should be the same width as your x-axis * -1:

```
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .tickFormat(formatNumber)
    .tickSize(-width)
    .ticks(3)
    .orient('left');
```

Comment: This worked great! Can you explain why the width should be the width of the x-axes * -1?

Comment: So I'm not 100% sure on the technicalities but I believe the ticks are by default starting from the y and going to the left. So to get them going to the right you need to send them into the negative x coordinate space of the ticks. Sorry if I haven't explained it well :)

Comment: No worries. That actually makes sense if that's how that works behind the scenes. Thanks again!